# Regex on generic files extensions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to design a regular expression able to capture:

1. `*.txt`
2. `*.txt|*cvs`

Regular expression must not capture: `toto.txt` or `*.txt;*.csv`

I thought about this one: `\*\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\|\*\.[a-zA-Z]+)*` but I capture `*.txt;*.csv` which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
^\*\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\|\*\.[a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `\*\.[a-zA-Z]+` Match `*.` followed by 1+ chars A-Za-z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\|\*\.[a-zA-Z]+` Match `|*.` followed by 1+ chars A-Za-z
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cgQco8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost closed to the solution, The fourth bird.
You missed in your example a '.' for second case.

Anyway, many thanks, it helped me to adjust the regexp to this one: `^\*\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\|\*\.[a-zA-Z]+)?$`

Here's the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cIjGLv/1)

Thanks again